# Implementing a search bar multiple times on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar embedded in all 4 navigation bars of my iOS app. All of the search bars read from the exact same data so my question is, do i have to setup a tableview and hook it up to the information for each view controller or can i hook all the search Bars to one "search view controller" and if so how do i implement this. Keep in mind I am developing for iOS 9 so please use the most up-to-date methods as a lot of search stuff has been depreciated in iOS 8. Thanks

Comment: If your navigationBar is highly customized one (eg. with searchBar) then consider dump the current navigationBar and create a class for it, then u can just create one and use it for anyview

Comment: so do i subclass uinavigationbar or uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Your `UINavigationController`, in `appdelegate` add that navigationcontroller as root viewcontroller, then change the top bar of any VC to `translucent navigation bar` then unhide it